# Google Maps API Layer with a continuous update of the GeoJSON

Tags: html, google-maps, maps, geojson

I'm working on a project and I need to update every X second a JSON file into my HTML page without reloading the whole page. I'm using google maps API and the JSON that I'm trying to load is a geoJson.
At the moment my HTML page looks like this:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwcEjr78AKq9cTP-dPWfFSeGaJ_-CkGSA">
    </script>    
    <script src="geoJsonInputData.js"></script>
    <script>
                var map;
                var myLocation = {
                    'latitude': 38.255753,
                    'longitude': 140.836304
                };

                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

                function initialize() {
                    // Create a map
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);
                    // Load a GeoJSON 
                    map.data.addGeoJson(data);
                }
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                setInterval(refreshData, 2000);

                function refreshData( )
                {
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(myLatlng);
                    map.data.addGeoJson(data);
                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see I'm trying to use the refreshData function to reload the variable Data that actually represent a geoJson but when I do it I obtain a google maps screen without map (there are the zoom and other buttons but I can't see the map) and to see the map again I have to refresh the page manually.

What I want, is to update the geoJson from the JS script automatically and without any visual problem.

Here is geoJsonInputData.js and in the variable Data you can see an example of my autogenerated geoJson:

```
var newLocation = {'latitude':140.836304,'longitude':38.255753};
var data ={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
{
"type":"Feature",
"properties": {},
"geometry":{
"type":"LineString",
"coordinates":
[[140.836304,38.255753],[140.83640400000002,38.255853],[140.83650400000002,38.255953000000005]]}
}
]
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Never heard of geoJson.  Does that do anything good for you?  Before I can answer, can you tell me what happens in geoJsonInputData.js ?  The error you get now, is on line 37: newLocation is unknown ( maybe it makes sense in "geoJsonInputData.js", I don't know ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my question with the file.

Comment: 1 detail: it is "LineString" with capital S. But that doesn't solve the whole problem; I still see a grey screen after the first refresh.  I would have to find out how GeoJSON works

Comment: I think that the problem is not related to GeoJSON because I tested it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dragndrop?hl=it and it works. Off course, I'm not sure...

Comment: Try [http://geojsonlint.com/](http://geojsonlint.com/), it doesn't like your posted geoJSON.  However when I change `Linestring` to `LineString`, it is OK.

Comment: Your [posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/emvg7g2d/)

Comment: Thank you, I changed the "Linestring" into "LineString" but I still have the same problem, grey screen after refresh. Also the link from geocodezip is not working. Can I ask you what kind of browser are you using?